# Seeking References: Theorem on Weak Convergence of Measures in Metric Spaces Beyond $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: measure-theory, reference-request, weak-convergence

Let $\mathcal{X}$ be a metric space and $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{X})$ denote its Borel sigma-algebra. Do you know any book or paper that provides a proof of the following theorem concerning weak convergence of finite measures? The classical books I have consulted only present proofs for measures on $\mathbb{R}$ or *probability* measures.

> Let $(\mathcal{X}, \mathcal{B} (\mathcal{X}))$ be a measurable space.
> Given $(\mu_n , n \geq 1 )$ a sequence of finite measures and $\mu$ another finite
> measure, all defined on $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{X})$. Then
> $\mu_n\Longrightarrow\mu$, $n \to \infty$, is equivalent to:
> \begin{equation}\label{weakconv1}
>      \int_{\mathcal{X}} g d \mu_n \longrightarrow \int_{\mathcal{X}} g d \mu,\quad \forall\, g \in \mathcal{C}(\mathcal{X}) \quad (n \to
>  \infty),  \end{equation}  where $\mathcal{C}(\mathcal{X})$ is the
> class of bounded continuous real functions defined on $\mathcal{X}$.

In fact, I need to cite in my work the the demonstration for measures on $\mathcal{X}=\mathbb R^n$.

The definition of $\mu_n\implies \mu$ is:

\begin{equation}\label{weakconv0}
    \mu_n(A) \longrightarrow \mu(A), \quad \forall\, A \in \mathcal{C}_\mu\quad (n \to \infty).
\end{equation}
where $\mathcal{C}_\mu$ is the class of continuity sets of $\mu$.

Comment: I suppose your measures are finite measures and $X$ is a metric space. A standard reference is Convergence of Probability Mesures by P Billingsley.

Comment: Yes. the measures are finite. But, the Billingsley's book is for probability measures. Are you saying that since the measure is finite I can normalize and work only with probability measures?

Comment: Yes, take $f\equiv 1$ to see that $\mu_n(X) \to \mu(X)$. This allows you to reduce the proof to the case of Probability measures.

Comment: Another standard reference is Parthasarathy, _Probability theory on metric spaces_

Comment: This is usually called [Portmanteau theorem](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Convergence_of_measures#Weak_convergence_of_measures), which is *Theorem 4.1* in the book [Markov Chains on Metric Spaces: A Short Course](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-031-11822-7).